# validate Bank sort code

Tags: c#

Is in the format XX-XX-XX (where X=a number). If entered without the dashes, format accordingly. If any of the digits are missing (e.g. 01-2-22, or 11556), a warning should be displayed to check the details.Please tell how to validate this

Thankyou

```
          string str_sortcode = txt_sortcode.Text;
            Regex r = new Regex(@"12-22-34");
            Match match1 = r.Match(str_sortcode);
            if (match1.Success)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                MainContent_updPanelError.Visible = true;
                lblerrr.Visible = true;
                lblerrr.Text = "Please enter a valid Bank Sort Code. For example: 12-22-34";
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

The regex you've given will only ever match the exact string `"12-22-34"`.

Your regex should look something like:

```
@"\b[0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{2}\b"
```

Which matches 3 sets of 2 digits, optionally separated by hyphens but no other character.

If you want to automatically add the dashes in, then you'd change the expression to:

```
@"\b([0-9]{2})-?([0-9]{2})-?([0-9]{2})\b"
```

And use `Regex.Replace` with this as the replacement:

```
@"$1-$2-$3"
```

This will turn `123456` -> `12-34-56`, and validate `12-34-56` as being correct, while `1234` and `12-34-5` as incorrect.

The reason for using `[0-9]` instead of `\d` is that `\d` will match numbers from other languages and character sets, but only 0-9 are valid for bank sort codes.

Comment: +1 still, but note this will accept `12-3456`, i.e 1 dash. greg84 has solved this.

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression is wrong. If you want to accept it **with or without** dashes, change it to this:

`Regex r = new Regex(@"\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{6}");`

To add the dashes in afterwards:

```
if (!str_sortcode.Contains("-"))
{
    str_sortcode = string.Join(
                            "-", 
                            new[] { 
                                str_sortcode.Substring(0, 2), 
                                str_sortcode.Substring(2, 2), 
                                str_sortcode.Substring(4, 2) 
                            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this, is:

```
^\d\d-\d\d-\d\d$
```

take a look:

http://tinyurl.com/pjq5a56

Comment: This regex matches `"abcd௫௬-௭௮-௯౦efgh"` - use `[0-9]` instead and surround it by word boundaries (`\b`)

Answer (score 0):

try use {*n*} to declare the number of digits

> {n}    n is a non-negative integer. Matches exactly n times. For example, "o{2}" does not match the "o" in "Bob," but matches the first two o's in "foooood".

{*n,m*} this is if you have a range of possible digits

> {n,m} m and n are non-negative integers. Matches at least n and at most m times. For example, "o{1,3}" matches the first three o's in "fooooood." "o{0,1}" is equivalent to "o?".

Answer (score 0):

Change your regular expressions with ^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression to test both cases (with and without dashes):

```
^               # Start of the string
(\d{2}          # Followed by a group of two digits
(-\d{2}){2})    # Followed by two groups of the form: -<digit><digit>
|\d{6}          # OR 6 digits
$               # End of the string
```

Don't forget to use `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` when creating your `Regex` instance if you copy the pattern from above.